# Error Ruby "Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1"

Tags: ruby, terminal, jekyll, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently cloned an existing repo I will be working on. The project uses Jekyll I installed ruby and followed each step from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/. When I go into the directory and type `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I get the error "Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1". I use ohmyzsh and Zsh and I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue. I don't want to mess with the gemfile. thank you.

Comment: What OS, how many versions of ruby & gem do you have installed, and where do they show up on your PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing repository uses ruby version "2.7.1", but your installed and selected ruby version is "3.0.2". Please switch to ruby version "2.7.1" and then try again

Comment: Thank you for your response! I ended up installing rvm and then installing ruby 2.7.1. Next in my directory I ran "bundle exec jekyll serve" followed by "bundle install" and that did the trick